# Creating a fixed UITextField - Obj C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `tablview` that populates cells.  When a cell is clicked I pragmatically populate `textfields` My question is how do I get the `y` coordinate so that I can position the `UITextField` based on where the user is currently located in the bounds?  Or either make it so that I set the `UITextField` as a fixed position so that if you were to scroll down in the tableview the `UITextField` would always remain in the same place.

I don't mind either option but what would be the best approach to this?

UPDATE:

Okay here is what I am asking.  When you populate a `tablview` with cells and it exceeds the screens physical seeing bounds you would scroll down to view the other cells right? So If i use:

```
float width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
self.cardnameTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 25)];
```

`0` = the `y` position.  So that will populate at the top of my `UiTableview` at the `0,0` position which will be located at the top most left of the `UITableView`.  Now what I am asking is lets say I scroll down to select a `cell` that exceeded the bounds of the physical screen and I selected the `cell`, it would populate the `UITextField` at the top most left of the `UITableView` `0,0` rather than the top most left of the physical screen.  How do I get the physical screens `y` coordinate so I can position the `UITextField` so that the user will always see it.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what it is you're asking for in this question. Can you visualize it in some way?

Comment: @ianmacdonald okay lets say you are looking at a table with 20 cells.  You scroll on your screen down to see all the cells correct?  Well when you click a cell at the bottom of the list, your going to be positioned pretty far down on your y cordinate.  My question is, how do you get that y cordinate that is with what the user sees on their screen.

Comment: You could use `[UIView convertRect:fromView]` to convert coordinates from your cell view to your view controller's view space, but there might be a better way to get to your end result. Can you draw a picture of what you're intending these `UITextField`s to be used for and where they should appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I just figured it out.

So when you execute `[self.viewaddSubview:self.cardnameTextField];` this will position it within the `UITableView` which I would than have to find the `y` coordinate of the actual screens most top position. But if I run `[self.view.window addSubview:self.cardnameTextField];` it sets it to the actual `window` giving it a almost `CSS` functionality of `position:fixed;` Which was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Yes. You need to read up on view hierarchy to understand this better.

Comment: @IanMacDonald yes found that out at the expense of my rep

Answer (score -1):

Even with your comment, it isn't very clear what you are asking.

If you are asking how to convert a cell's position to screen coordinates, it's pretty easy. UIView has a whole family of methods for converting coordinates from one view's coordinate system to another. They work as long as the 2 views are part of the same view hierarchy. You might take the cell's contentView.bounds.origin (which will be in the content view's coordinate system and) convert the position to the view controller content view's coordinate system:

```
CGPoint cellOrigin = cell.contentView.bounds.origin;

cellOrigin = [self.view convertPoint: cellOrigin fromView: cell.contentView];
```

The above code would give you the coordinates of a cell's origin, in the coordinates of the view controller's content view.

If that's NOT what you're asking then you will need to update your question to make it clear WHAT you are asking.

Comment: Who down-voted me, and why? I did my best to answer the (very vague) question based on what I could understand. I guess I missed the mark in my understanding, but that's hardly my fault...